# How to solve this matrix inequality?

Tags: matrices, inequality, positive-definite, linear-matrix-inequality

Let $C$ be a given (known) matrix and let $\theta$ be a given (known)
positive real. We would like to determine the matrices $X$ and $Y$
and diagonal matrix $P$ solving the following inequality

\begin{equation}
(XC)^{\text{T}}e{}^{(-YC)^{\text{T}}\theta}Pe{}^{(-YC)\theta}(XC)-P\prec0,
\end{equation}

which is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
P-(XC)^{\text{T}}e{}^{(-YC)^{\text{T}}\theta}Pe{}^{(-YC)\theta}(XC)\succ0.
\end{equation}
or 
\begin{equation}
P-(XC)^{\text{T}}e{}^{(-YC)^{\text{T}}\theta}PP^{-1}Pe{}^{(-YC)\theta}(XC)\succ0.
\end{equation}
Using Schur complement, it is equivalent to 
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}P & (XC)^{\text{T}}e{}^{(-YC)^{\text{T}}\theta}\\
e^{(-YC)\theta}(XC) & P^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}\succ0,
\end{equation}
or 
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}P & (XC)^{\text{T}}e{}^{(-YC)^{\text{T}}\theta}P\\
Pe^{(-YC)\theta}(XC) & P
\end{bmatrix}\succ0.
\end{equation}

Does anyone know how to transform these inequalities into linear matrix
inequalities (LMIs) please? Or does anyone know how to solve these
inequalities in order to find the matrices $X$ and $Y$ please? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide background and motivation. Does this come from the stability of discrete-time linear systems?

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo. Yes, it comes from the stability of discrete-time linear systems. I am actually dealing with linear impulsive systems.

Answer (score 2):

Choosing $\mathrm X = \mathrm I$ and $\mathrm Y = \mathrm O$, we obtain the following Lyapunov [linear matrix inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_matrix_inequality) (LMI) in $\mathrm P$

$$\mathrm C^{\top} \mathrm P \, \mathrm C - \mathrm P \prec \mathrm O$$

We can choose a *positive* definite matrix $\mathrm Q$ and solve the following [Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation) in $\mathrm P$

$$\mathrm C^{\top} \mathrm P \, \mathrm C - \mathrm P + \mathrm Q = \mathrm O$$

[Vectorizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)), we obtain a system of linear equations

$$\left( \mathrm I - (\mathrm C \otimes \mathrm C)^{\top} \right) \mbox{vec} (\mathrm P) = \mbox{vec} (\mathrm Q)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Rodrigo. The case $X = I$ and $Y = 0$ is a trivial case. However, we are more interested in how to solve this inequality in general cases.